# Better way to convert slice of int to hex value

Tags: go, slice

I have a slice of int containing only zeros and ones (`[]int{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}`)

I want to convert the string representation to hex value.  I'm converting the slice of ints to a slice of strings then doing a `strconv.ParseUint` to convert.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func IntToString(values []int) string {
    valuesText := []string{}
    for i := range values {
        valuesText = append(valuesText, strconv.Itoa(values[i]))
    }
    return strings.Join(valuesText, "")
}

func IntSliceToHex(in []int) (string, error) {
    intString := IntToString(in)
    ui, err := strconv.ParseUint(intString, 2, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%X", ui), nil
}

func HexToBin(hex string) (string, error) {
    ui, err := strconv.ParseUint(hex, 16, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%b", ui), nil
}

func main() {
    profile := []int{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}

    hex, err := IntSliceToHex(profile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    bin, err := HexToBin(hex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(hex, bin)
}
```

OUTPUT: F0F 111100001111

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use bitshift operations to build up the actual number from the slice rather than converting each bit to string and parsing it.

You should also keep the built-up integer rather than converting back and forth to a string.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    profile := []int{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

    final := uint64(profile[0])
    for i := 1; i < len(profile); i++ {
        final <<= 1
        final += uint64(profile[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("%X %b\n", final, final)
    // Output: FFFFFFFFFFFF0000 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000
}
```

**Note**: `final` is an unsigned 64 bit integer and can handle `profile` slices of length up to (and including) 64. For larger sizes, use [big.Int](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int).

Comment: Wow that is pretty neat!  I'm not too familiar with bitshift operations so I'll have to read up on it.  My example had a shortened slice of ints.  In my case it would be a slice of 64 ints.  I get a totally different result.

profile := []int{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   

Output: -10000 -10000000000000000

Comment: Tweaked the sample code. With 64 bits, this is an unsigned 64 bit integer. If you have more, you'll need to use something else (like a [big.Int](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int))